# How many random bits does this algoithm use on average (expected value)?

Tags: algorithm, probability, probability-distribution, bernoulli-probability

Here, `flip()` is a function that returns `0` or `1` with equal probability. It can be proved function `Random(n)` returns a number from `0` to `n-1` with identically distributed probabilities (using loop invariant).

```
function Random(n):
    v = 1;
    c = 0;
    loop
        v = 2v;
        c = 2c + flip();
        if (v >= n) then
            if (c < n) then
                return c;
            else
                v = v - n;
                c = c - n;
            end if
        end if
    end loop
end function
```

My question is how many random bits does this algorithm use in average (expected value of calling `flip()` function)?

I know it takes `[logn]+1` times doubling `v` to reach `n`. Then with probability of `n/v = n/v^([logn]+1)` algorithm finishes. If it didn't finish, algorithm starts again. Here we don't know whether doubling `v` will cause `v >= n` or not and chhecking probability would be hard. How can I face this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might try to figure it out for n = 1, n = 2, n = 3, ... and then guess an equation which you can prove by induction. Also, seems like this question is more suitable for cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com; it's off topic for SO since it isn't a specific programming problem.

Comment: The average bits is a complicated function of `n`. Are you looking for reasonable bounds, a floating point approximation, or an exact fraction?

Comment: For a problem like this, I like to start with a Monte Carlo simulation. Basically, you call the function many times, and create a histogram of the `flip` count for each call. The histogram can be used to compute the average, and the distribution in the histogram can give you insights as to why that average was obtained. The key to success with Monte Carlo simulations is to use a good random number generator, such as `arc4random_uniform`.